# Suggestions for using Spark in AWS without any cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to leverage a couple Spark APIs to convert some data in an EC2 container. We deploy these containers on Kubernetes.

I'm not super familiar with Spark, but I see there are requirements on Spark context, etc. Is it possible for me to just leverage the Spark APIs/RDDs, etc without needing any cluster? I just have a simple script I want to run that leverages Spark. I was thinking I could somehow fatjar this dependency or something, but not quite sure what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a cluster to run spark.
***Cluster is nothing more than a platform to install Spark***

I think your question should be "**Can Spark run on single/standalone node ?**"
If this you want to know then yes spark can run on standalone node as spark has its own stand alone cluster.

"but I see there are requirements on Spark context":

SparkContext is the entry point of spark, you need to create it in order to use any spark function.

Comment: If I have an application "HelloWorld" for example, can I submit the job within the same container? Do I package the Spark deps as some uber jar in the container?

Comment: yes you need to create a jar and then spark submit to run on AWS